# using soup,find_all returns a [ ] value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using soup, find_all returns empty list

code:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"xml")

# returns:
soup.findAll("div", {"class":"D(ib) Mend(20px)"})
# []
```

Comment: thanks for your help as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the returned-request to a string before passing it to Beautiful-soup.

This works:

```
r=requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB")
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(r.text))
# print(soup)
res = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "D(ib) Mend(20px)"})
```

It returned:

```
[<div class="D(ib) Mend(20px)" data-reactid="31"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="32">261.36</span><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($negativeColor)" data-reactid="33">-1.75 (-0.67%)</span><div class="C($tertiaryColor) D(b) Fz(12px) Fw(n) Mstart(0)--mobpsm Mt(6px)--mobpsm" data-reactid="34" id="quote-market-notice"><span data-reactid="35">At close:  4:00PM EST</span></div></div>]
```

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\BICS\Documents\TEST BEAUTIFUL SOUP\beautifulSoup live data method.py", line 6
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(r.text))
GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

Comment: The code that caused this warning is on line 6 of the file C:\Users\BICS\Documents\TEST BEAUTIFUL SOUP\beautifulSoup live data method.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

Comment: i tried modifying the BeautifulSoup constructor soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(r.text,features="lxml")) but get another error

Comment: ERROR NOW:  soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(r.text,features="lxml"))
TypeError: 'features' is an invalid keyword argument for str()

Comment: The features argument needs to be outside the str().

Comment: i updated as soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(r.text),features="lxml")
works good with no error but then the code gives no return answer when running completely i have to enter the command manually to get a result.

Comment: i have to go into the shell manually enter soup.findAll("div", {"class": "D(ib) Mend(20px)"}) then i get a result but defeats the purpose of the python script? right?

Comment: Manually as in? Can you please paste your script here?
Just fyi, you do have the last line: `res = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "D(ib) Mend(20px)"}); print(res)` in your script right?

Comment: i had to take the "res =" part out.

Comment: def parsePrice():
    r=requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NOK?p=NOK")
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(r.text),features="lxml")
    price = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"D(ib) Mend(20px)"})[0].find("span").text
    return price

while True:
    print ("the current price: " +str (parsePrice()))
    #NOKIAlive = [str (parsePrice())]
    LIVEprice = str (parsePrice())
    print (LIVEprice)

Comment: sorry my formatting in the comment box here, did not come out too clear. hard to read

Comment: Your initial question was about not being able to parse the `"class":"D(ib) Mend(20px)"` element. I think we already established we are able to do that. Right?

Comment: When you find an answer helpful, the least you can do is to upvote it, so others can find it helpful if they face similar issues in the future.

Comment: How do i "upvote it"? sorry i'm a newbee here. Thnx!